# Codimension of linear subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the codimension of X? X is subset of space of $2\times 2$ matrices $M_{2\times 2}$.
\begin{equation}
X=\left\{\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 0 \\
  0 & x
\end{array}\right)\bigg| x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}
\end{equation}
I think that the codimension is two, because dimension of $M_{2\times 2}$ is four, and dimension of $X$ is two, then the codimension is $4-2$. What do you think?
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension of $X$ is $1$, since its elements only depend on the single parameter $x$. The dimension of $M_{2x2}$ is, as you said, 4. The codimension is therefore $4 - 1 = 3$.

Answer (score 0):

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$
is a basis of $X$. Hence the dimension of $X$ is 1.
Since the dimension of $M_{2\times 2}$ is 4, the codimension of $X$ is 3.